# Two lists in a single variable

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

This is part of my parsed xml file

```
- <a:p>
    - <a:r>
          <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="3600" dirty="0" /> 
          <a:t>36%</a:t> 
     </a:r>
  </a:p>
- <a:p>
    - <a:r>
          <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="3600" dirty="0" smtClean="0" /> 
          <a:t /> 
      </a:r>
      <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="3600" dirty="0" /> 
  </a:p>
  </p:txBody>
  </p:sp>
```

I have to extarct the text from `a:t` tags and the code snippet is beolw!!

```
path1 = file.xpath('/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p', namespaces=NAMESPACES)    
for a in path1:
    b = a.xpath('./a:r/a:rPr[@sz="3600" and @dirty="0"]',namespaces=NAMESPACES)
    for c in b:
        d = c.getparent().getparent()
        e = d.xpath('./a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces=NAMESPACES)
        print e
```

I have a variable which consists of two lists as an output.. for example

`print e`

results in

```
['38%']
[' ']
```

Now, I would like  to remove the second list i.e `[' ']` and print only `['38%']`

any suggestion how i could do that? I never came across such situation before since i started learning lists

Comment: what is the type of `e`? To print in that way, it is almost certainly a string. Please show the output of `repr(e)`.

Comment: Do you always want to print only the first list? Or is there some criterion for choosing which lists to show?

Comment: @interjay I always want to print the first list!!

Comment: @Sangamesh It would be a good idea, as Marcin said, to show output of `repr(e)` your question is currently ambiguous

Comment: `e = d.xpath('./a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces=NAMESPACES)` when i print the value of `e` I get two lists as result and i want to keep only the first one. @Marcin I have represented the output in the question itself for your reference!

Comment: What you showed in the question is not helpful because it isn't clear what the type of `e` is. What library are you using that contains the `xpath` method?

Comment: @interjay  print type(e) results `<type 'list'>` `<type 'list'>`

Comment: @interjay I am using lxml library for xpath

Comment: @Sangamesh Please do not use print. Please type exactly `repr(e)` into your python console, and copy the whole line containing the statement, and the entire output down to the following prompt.

Comment: @jamylak I tried repr(e) but it does not give any output.. Sorry guys I am still a learner..

Comment: @Sangamesh Put the whole transcript that I requested in your question.

Comment: I think what happened is that you put the `print e` line inside a loop in your script (or a function that is called more than once), so it actually ran twice. Please check if that is the case. The fact that you say `print type(e)` showed two types makes this very likely.

Comment: There is no way you can have "two lists in a single variable". You can have one `list` (or one `tuple` or one `foo.bar.Baz`) in a variable, where that `list` contains two lists as elements. If that's the case, we need to know what type of thing you have, before we can tell you how to get the first element.

Comment: @Marcin `e = d.xpath('./a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces=NAMESPACES)` and i do repr(e) doesnt give me anything!!

Comment: All that being said, there's a decent chance that all you need is `e[0]` here.

Comment: @Sangamesh What is that supposed to be? Put ALL RELEVANT CODE and ALL RELEVANT TRANSCRIPTS **IN THE BODY OF YOUR QUESTION**. Do NOT put them in comments.

Comment: @abarnert I did that it gives me both e[0] values from both lists..

Comment: OK, [`lxml.xpath` returns a `list`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) of matches. So, if you just want the first match, that's `e[0]`. However, the matches it returns are not lists, so you must be doing this twice (e.g., in a loop, as `interjay` suggested) and printing out `e` each time. And, since you haven't shown us the relevant code, there is no way we can tell you how to fix it, as Marcin said.

Comment: @Marcin hope the question is much clear now!

Comment: @abarnert the code snippet is shown above in the question for your reference!!

Comment: @Sangamesh: It's still not really clear without the input data. Ideally, you should give us a stripped-down example with all of the code and input data needed to run it outselves. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for details. Otherwise, you're forcing us to guess what might be wrong in code or data that we can't actually see, so you're going to get useless answers, repeated requests for followups, downvotes, close votes, etc.

Comment: @abarnert the part of my parsed `xml` file is shown above..could u please suggest how could i skip that missing value and print only the first `a:t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable that contains a single list, with a single string in it.

This is obvious now that you've told us how you get the value:

```
e = d.xpath('./a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces=NAMESPACES)
```

[lxml's `xpath` method returns a `list`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) of things, which, when `repr`'d, represent as strings. So, `['38%']` and `[' ']` are both things you could see when `print`ing the result.

The problem is clearly that you're searching for `e` twice, and `print`ing it twice (or doing a similar search and print elsewhere).

From your edit:

```
path1 = file.xpath('/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p', namespaces=NAMESPACES)    
for a in path1:
    b = a.xpath('./a:r/a:rPr[@sz="3600" and @dirty="0"]',namespaces=NAMESPACES)
    for c in b:
        d = c.getparent().getparent()
        e = d.xpath('./a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces=NAMESPACES)
        print e
```

You have the `e = …` and `print e` inside a loop. Either your `a` search returns two elements (each of which has a `b` search that returns 1 element), or your `b` search does.

If you want only the first result of anything, you can just stop looping once you get to the `print`. For example, if this is inside a function:

```
path1 = file.xpath('/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p', namespaces=NAMESPACES)    
for a in path1:
    b = a.xpath('./a:r/a:rPr[@sz="3600" and @dirty="0"]',namespaces=NAMESPACES)
    for c in b:
        d = c.getparent().getparent()
        e = d.xpath('./a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces=NAMESPACES)
        print e
        return
```

However, if you want to actually understand what's going on, you should try printing out the values at multiple steps:

```
path1 = file.xpath('/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p', namespaces=NAMESPACES)
print path1
for a in path1:
    b = a.xpath('./a:r/a:rPr[@sz="3600" and @dirty="0"]',namespaces=NAMESPACES)
    print ' ', b
    for c in b:
        d = c.getparent().getparent()
        e = d.xpath('./a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces=NAMESPACES)
        print e
```

Comment: Thats right!! there is a missing value where i am looping through..i found it..Thanks